# Building multiple ports (using macports) at the same time

Tags: macos, gcc, build, gfortran, macports

I'm trying to build gcc45 +gfortran on my macbook pro core duo 2 and obviously it is taking a while (A few hours I'm told). I'm wondering if its possible (safe) if I build some other ports / packages in another terminal in the mean time?

Answer (score 2):

Building multiple ports in parallel is blocked by a lock-file.

You could override that but it is not safe to do so.